# 'refresh' jquery UI selectmenu after update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an get request which fetches a bunch of category information to populate a `<select>`. I'm using jQuery UI Selectmenu to style my select.

So my jQuery looks a little like this:

```
//Initalise the selectmenu
$("select").selectmenu({ style: 'dropdown' });

$.get("http://localhost/somedata?cat=2", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
        $("<option value='" + itemData.Id + "'>" + itemData.Name + "</option>").appendTo("#selectList");
    });
});
```

However this populates the `<select>` but does not update the jQuery UI selectmenu. Any ideas what I need to do to get the selectmenu to be 're-drawn' so the new values appear in the selectmenu?

Comment: Please note: there a three version of selectmenu with different functionality, API and documentation! Which version do you use? Code example? See the wiki for more information: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu

Comment: this does help me $(document).on('change', "body", function(){
    $( ".ui-selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
});

Answer (score 25):

You can use the aptly-named `refresh` method, documented in the [development wiki](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138056/Selectmenu):

```
$("select").selectmenu({ style: 'dropdown' });

$.get("http://localhost/somedata?cat=2", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, itemData) {
        $("<option value='" + itemData.Id + "'>" + itemData.Name
            + "</option>").appendTo("#selectList");
    });

    $("select").selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

**Update:** Unfortunately, the `refresh` function is documented but does not seem to be implemented yet. Another option is to destroy the widget and recreate it:

```
$("select").selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu({ style: "dropdown" });
```

Comment: $("select").selectmenu("refresh"); Doesn't seem to have any effect, gets called but no effect on the jQuery UI element.

Comment: @CLiown, that's unfortunate. I checked both repositories listed in the wiki, and the `refresh` method does not seem to be implemented yet. It will probably be by the time this widget becomes available in the main tree. On the other hand, recreating the widget through a call to `selectmenu()` may not work in the future, in that case you might want to destroy the widget beforehand, e.g. with `$("select").selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu({style: "dropdown"});`.

Comment: $("select").selectmenu("destroy").selectmenu({ style: "dropdown" }); did the trick for me. Thank you!

Comment: The selectmenu('refresh') works now and is the correct answer.

Comment: Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Here is a link that answers the question a little better with fewer words... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273176/jqueryui-selectmenu-how-to-add-more-options

Comment: @Juan, which is the better answer? The one that says "this will work" without any explanation, or the one that says "depends on the version" with two github links?

Answer (score 2):

That's a very old question so currently there is [a much simpler solution](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) available:

```
$("select").selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: Not odd, hopefully you can see from previous comments that in 2012 "refresh" didn't work but did start working in 2015.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I was searching for an answer in 2019 and didn't see it until seeing your comment and pressing "see more replies". Hope this will help someone like me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Ill recommend the ajax way..try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
                   url :/somedata?cat=2,          

                   success:function(data){
                        $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
        $("<option value='" + itemData.Id + "'>" + itemData.Name + "</option>").appendTo("#selectList");
    });

                   }
                });
$("select").selectmenu({ style: 'dropdown' });
});
```