# Set a jQuery UI selectmenu to a specific option by javascript

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a selectmenu like the following

```
<select name="scale" id="scale">
  <option selected>linear</option>
  <option>root</option>
  <option>square</option>
</select>
```

To make it nice I use jQuery UI v1.11.2.

```
$('#scale').selectmenu();
```

I can now read the value of the dropdown by

```
alert($('#scale').val());
```

which results in 'linear' as the answer. I can also set the value to 'square' by using

```
$('#scale').val('square');
alert($('#scale').val());
```

which correctly gives the answer 'square'. But (!!!) the dropdown does not display this on the screen. So actually I can set and read the value, but the visual representation doesn't change - the widget does not refresh. I read somewhere to throw a `.change()` but without any effect. I also tried answers like in [jQuery UI Selectmenu value set dynamically does not change visible selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917516/jquery-ui-selectmenu-value-set-dynamically-does-not-change-visible-selected-valu/9917781#9917781) but failed. Any `$('#scale').selectmenu('value', 'square');` resuts in the error message `Error: no such method 'value' for selectmenu widget instance`.

Can anyone help how to refresh the widget after setting it to a new value?

Comment: It should work as you expect it to if you just call [`refresh`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) after using `.val()`: `$("#scale").selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: @blgt please post that as an answer. Don't leave questions unanswered by answering in comments...

Comment: @TJ Done. I'd say this question is better off closed though, as it's not very likely to help anyone other than the OP (thus the comment and the close-vote)

Comment: @blgt Hmm I think this might help someone in future, unless it is an exact duplicate of the question mentioned in the original post...

Comment: @TJ No, the linked question is about a separate plugin called *selectmenu*. The `selectmenu` here is a new widget in the latest incarnation of the $.ui; whether the two are linked in any way I have no idea :) The close-vote was an opinion, I admit on a second glance I may have been wrong

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It should work as you expect it to if you just call [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh) after using `.val()`:

```
$('#scale').val('square');
$("#scale").selectmenu("refresh");
```

The reason for this is that the `.val()` function is provided by jQuery, while the widget is part of jQueryUI. [presumably the $.ui authors didn't want to alter the $ functionality, though this is purely speculation on my part]

Comment: I think is a best answer. Thanks blgt

Comment: You can also make it in one line `$('#scale').val('square').selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: I thought this didn't work but I realized the value I was setting was not present